# Adding a DIV from a file named A to a new window opened using window.open() from file named B in grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

I have a template named _A.gsp.In it some search results are shown.When each result is clicked,a new window is opened.I have coded for this as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function openWin()
       {
          myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
          myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
          myWindow.focus();
       }
</script>
```

This is the body:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="small"><g:message code="Company Names"/></th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <g:each in="${results}" >
       <tr>
         <td>
         <a onclick="openWin();" > ${results}</a>


         </td>

       </tr>
    </g:each>
</tbody>
```

This is working fine.Now what i need is that the new window should show a particular div say id="profile", when opened instead of what it is showing now.This div is in a separate file say _B.gsp. How can I do that using the same window.open()?

Comment: have us used template _a.gsp in _b.gsp??

Comment: No _b.gsp is independent of _a.gsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a sample example on my side. I create a template named _test.gsp and test this scenario .

```
<r:script type="text/javascript">
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<div id='profile'>"+ "${g.render(template: 'test')}" +"</div>");
    myWindow.focus();
}
</r:script>
<a onclick="openWin();">Open</a>
```

Here is my template _test.gsp:

```
<p>
Hello
</p>
```

It working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Its not working for me.Now the popup also is not appearing.I also created _test.gsp containing only the div with id profile' and called it like above.But still no way.can you post the complete code of what you tried?

Comment: can you plz explain me what is the use of ${g.render(template: 'addressBook')} here

Comment: I have committed it accidentally. I have delete it now.

Comment: @user1791574 This is exactly what I am looking for! Your solution is opening the popup window **but** instead of rendering the content in my template (`_test.gsp`) file, it is just printing `${g.render(template: 'test')}` on screen. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks!